# Can we deploy windows phone app on android or iOS platform using VS 2012 or any other tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I have made a windows phone app, and wish to deploy my app on android and iOS platform too.
Can we use VS 2012 or any other tools for achieving the same.
I found the below link for reference:
http://nakedalm.com/deploy-from-visual-studio-2012-to-ios-windows-phone-android-and-windows/

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I have not evaluated the product, so you might want to talk to the ALM folks for clarification... What I've seen in the past are (1) a program reduced to HTML/CSS/JavaScript and run with a UIWebView or WebView like a standard browser app, and (2) an custom runtime library. Wikipedia [lists a bunch of similar IDE/Runtimes/Libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development). What I'm not clear on is the ability deploy to any platform from Visual Studio. I know Apple controls the USB data cable, so only Apple can use it. Perhaps ALM has a mobile component for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you're looking for is [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/). It will not directly make your Windows Phone app an Android or iOS app, but it will let you write code using C# and VS2012 and with the right approach achieve a high degree of code commonality between the different platforms.

It's not a magic bullet, but it's probably the best approach available to you.

Comment: Yes I have read about Xamarin which help for cross platform purpose, but do I have to write code all over again or can I upload my existing code there.
Also do we have to pay anything for it.
Sorry but I am not aware of this.